# makefile target-specific changing srcs files

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to write a Makefile with a rule to make the project with another main.cpp file, because I'm testing my code with different options

I have different versions of the main function, that I put inside differents files : `main.cpp`, `main_1.cpp`, `main_2.cpp`, ..., to test different versions of my code, and they all have the same dependencies

first I was just commenting and un-commenting the Makefile variable `MAIN` that define the main.cpp file, but I was hoping there is a way to choose the one I want to try with a specific rule ?

I tried something with target-specific variables but it didn't work :

```makefile
# # # # # # #
# VARIABLES #
# # # # # # #

NAME     = my_program
VPATH    = srcs
CXX      = c++ 
CXXFLAGS = -I ./headers
OBJS     = $(SRCS:%.cpp=%.o)

MAIN     = main.cpp
#MAIN     = main_1.cpp
SRCS     = $(MAIN) file.cpp


# # # # #
# RULES #
# # # # #

all: $(NAME)

# target-specific variables
test-1: MAIN = main_1.cpp
test-1: re

$(NAME) : $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(OBJS) -o $(NAME)
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS)
fclean: clean
    rm -f $(NAME)
re: fclean all 
.PHONY : all clean fclean re
```

the error output for `main test_1` is :

```
c++ -I ./headers   -c -o main.o srcs/main.cpp
c++ -I ./headers   -c -o file.o srcs/file.cpp
c++ main_1.o Webserv.o -o my_program
c++: error: main_1.o: No such file or directory
Makefile:21: recipe for target 'my_program' failed
make: *** [my_program] Error 1
```

I think, then, that target-specific is not the right tool for what I'm trying to do.

Does Make provide a way to accomplish that (modifying the list of srcs files when calling a specific rule, and having the compilation working great with the new srcs files) ?

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to accomplish. A more common approach to what I think you're hoping to achieve is to have a single `.cpp` file with `#define`s for things you want to override, and a separate `debug` target or similar which builds with those overrides, typically with a different target name so you're able to know what's where and avoid mistakes like publishing a test or debug version to production.

Comment: I see. But i don't have the problem of production or test state, it's just an exercise from school, and I'm trying to understand some new concepts. I find different ways to implement it, so I'm trying some of them, which leads to very different main() functions, and #defines will do very badly the job I think. First I was commenting and un-commenting the differents versions, but now I have too much of them, so I made severall main_x.cpp files. And I'm commenting the ones I don't want, inside the MAIN variable in the Makefile, but I thought maybe there is a way to choose the version with a rule

Comment: Still, please [edit] your question to clarify what "that" is and how `main_1` is related to `main`. I'm guessing it's a copy of the file with some changes, and that you want it to have the same dependencies etc...? And the error transcript is from `make test-1`?

Comment: edits done, you were guessing right. There is an error in my code example that I didn't correct because it's not relevant I think : since I change the MAIN definition, it's the wrong main_x.cpp file that will be `rm` with the clean rule, but it doesn't occurs in my real code because I delete a folder containing all the obj files, which means I use an explicit rule to compile the objects files, but I think it's not necessary for my question

Comment: Why not simply passing the `MAIN` make variable on the command line: `make MAIN=main_1.cpp`?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet for my usage, that works great :) thx !

Answer (score 0):

I'm vaguely thinking something like this.

```
test-%: main_%.cpp file.cpp
```

Now, `make test-1` will produce an executable with that name from `main_1.cpp` instead of `main.cpp`, and similarly `test-2` from `main_2.cpp`, etc.

If you have subsequent targets which hardcode `my_program` which should actually depend on which version you made, this might not be suitable, or at a minimum, you'd have to refactor those to use the current output executable. Similarly, you might want to add `test-[1-9]` to the files to remove in the `clean` target (or perhaps add a `realclean` target to remove them too).

Tangentially, several of your `make` variables don't seem to serve any immediate purpose. Putting stuff in variables makes sense for things you want to be able to override at compile time, or vaguely for making a general-purpose `Makefile` which can be applied with only minor modifications across several projects; but in isolation, these seem like unnecessary complexities you should probably avoid for the time being.

Your immediate problem could perhaps be solved by refactoring the dependency chain, but on the whole, I'd recommend keeping it as simple as possible. `make` already knows how to compile common source formats; all you really need to put in the `Makefile` are the dependencies which are not trivially obvious and any `.PHONY` targets, and overrides to select e.g. a specific default action.

Comment: about your general advice on Makefiles, I was inspired by this one : https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/08/26/makefile-c-projects and I guess it's not what you would recommend. Do you have an example of what you're saying ?

Comment: about you proposal for solution, I can't make it works, or I don't understand it : you remove the line `test-1: re` and you change the line above by the one you proposed ?